# Is it possible to use eclipse on Windows without a JDK?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to use Eclipse on my school laptop, but, my school wont give me permission to install the JDK.

Comment: If they won't let you install a JDK, how can you install Eclipse?

Comment: You can run Eclipse and the JDK from a USB key. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913515/is-there-a-way-to-install-java-7-onto-a-usb-and-use-that-for-projects-in-eclipse

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: eclipse does not need to be installed to run - just unpacked

Comment: @dystroy That should be an answer, not a comment, since it's the right answer :)

Comment: You don't need permission to download the Eclipse file.

Comment: You don't have to "install" a JDK it per se, if you download it and unzip it, it should work, as long as you can change the environment variables of JAVA_HOME and PATH

Comment: Whenever I open eclipse.exe I get an error that says a JRE or JDK is required to run Eclipse.

Comment: @user2288153 You have to edit the eclipse.ini file and change the `-vm` parameter to point to your JDK which may be on the USB drive.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't need a JDK, only a JRE as it brings it's own compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can get Eclipse onto your school computer is probably because Eclipse is just a zip file that they let you extract.  The reason you can't get the JDK onto your school computer is probably because the JDK has a formal "installer" that requires administrative permissions to run.  However, Eclipse does not need the JDK to be formally "installed" to use it.  It is enough to copy the JDK folder onto the computer you want to run Eclipse on.  So find a computer you can install the JDK on and install it there.  Then copy the JDK folder from that computer to your school computer.

Before you start, make sure you download the JDK with the same [bitness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bitness) as the Eclipse version you downloaded.  64-bit Eclipse needs a 64-bit JDK.  32-bit Eclipse needs a 32-bit JDK.

Copy

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdkX.x.x_xx
```

to some location on your school computer's hard drive.  Then edit (with a text editor) eclipse.ini.  The eclipse.ini file is located in the same directory as eclipse.exe. Add the two lines:

```
-vm
C:/path/to/the/jdk/folder/on/the/school/computer/jdkX.x.x_xx/bin/javaw.exe
```

Obviously substitute *C:/path/to/the/jdk/folder/on/the/school/computer/* with the actual location that you copied the JDK to.

Comment: I hope he extracts his jdk to `C:/path/to/the/jdk/folder/on/the/school/computer/`

Comment: Didn't seem to work. I got the same error "Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Users\name\Documents\eclipse\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"." even after editing the .ini.

Comment: Make sure you use the JDK with the same bitness as your Eclipse.  64-bit Eclipse needs a 64-bit JDK.  32-bit Eclipse needs a 32-bit JDK.

Comment: They are both for 64-bit.

Comment: It works for me :(.  I have in my eclipse.ini: `-vm C:/java/jdk1.6.0_22-64/bin/javaw.exe`.  And then on my hard drive I have: `C:\java\jdk1.6.0_22-64\bin\javaw.exe`.  Maybe try `C:\java\jdk1.6.0_22-64\jre\bin\javaw.exe` (note the 'jre' subfolder in there).  But I think it should work without that, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Is the -vm command added on a new line?

Comment: Yes, two separate lines.  Example: http://pastebin.com/PEwVT6z6

Comment: I still have the same error. Is it okay if the JRE folder is in the eclipse folder?

Comment: It's allowed to put the JRE/JDK folder inside the eclipse folder.  That would not be the problem.  I assure you that this approach works if you get everything done right (bitness, paths, etc.) so double check everything.

Comment: Hmm. It I got a new message that said that Eclipse has started but returned exit code=13.

Comment: Then you probably have matched a 32-bit JRE/JDK with 64-bit Eclipse or vice-versa.  Re-download the 64-bit versions of both to make sure you've got the right ones.  You want `eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip` and `jdk-7u21-windows-x64.exe`.  Notice the "64" in both filenames.

Answer (score 10):

You can run Eclipse and the JDK from an USB key without even having to install them. You can edit the eclipse.ini file to point to your JDK on the key as shown in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913515/is-there-a-way-to-install-java-7-onto-a-usb-and-use-that-for-projects-in-eclipse). You don't even have to change environment variables.

Note that this works also for other RCP based applications, that's how I deploy RCP applications on restricted computers in some companies.

Comment: I got a new error that says "Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Users\name\Documents\eclipse\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"."